# How do I return the number of times each name appears in a file? [Command Line]

Tags: shell, command-line

Given a file with an unspecified amount of names, how do I count the number of times each of those names appears in the file without knowing the name being searched for?

Yes, awkward spacing of names between commas is part of the file's standard expected format.

Sample_Names.txt :

```
Adam, Bob ,Billy, Cassandra ,Cally , Catherine, George
Amanda, Bob , Cassandra , Harry, Julie
Adam, Bob ,Billy, Harry, Larry
```

I'm currently at this configuration for a command:

```
awk -F , '{for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) grep $i | wc -l;}' Sample_Names.txt
```

This returns:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near wc
```

Successful execution of Command(s) or Shell script should return a file that looks like:

```
Adam 2
Amanda 1
Billy 2
 Bob  3
Cally  1
 Cassandra  2
 Catherine 1
 George 1
 Harry 2
 Julie 1
 Larry 1
```

or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU utils:

```
tr -s ',' '\n' < example.txt | sed 's/^[ ]*//; s/[ ]*$//' | sort | uniq -c
   2 Adam
   1 Amanda
   2 Billy
   3 Bob
   1 Cally
   2 Cassandra
   1 Catherine
   1 George
   2 Harry
   1 Julie
   1 Larry
```

Explanation:

`tr -s ',' '\n' < example.txt` <- replace all commas with newlines

`sed 's/^[ ]*//; s/[ ]*$//'` <- remove any whitespace before and after each name

`sort | uniq -c` <- sort the names, then count the occurrence of each name

--

You can also use awk to reorder the output if required, e.g.

```
tr -s ',' '\n' < example.txt | sed 's/^[ ]*//; s/[ ]*$//' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
Adam 2
Amanda 1
Billy 2
Bob 3
Cally 1
Cassandra 2
Catherine 1
George 1
Harry 2
Julie 1
Larry 1
```

Comment: Suggestion: you can lose sed with: `tr -s '[:space:],' '\n'`. Also, your answer (and this suggestion) are 100% POSIX. Including `tr -s` and `uniq -c`.

Answer (score 1):

With your awk, `-F ,` sets field separator to comma alone, but you still need spaces.

If you want to run shell commands from awk, you need `system()`.

But that's not necessary, you can use pure awk:

```
awk -F '[[:space:],]+' '
{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         names[$i]++
     }
}
END {
    for (i in names) {
        print names[i]"\t"i
    }
}'
```

You can pipe this to `sort -rnk 1,1` to sort by frequency.

If you have `grep -o`, there's also:

```
grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn -k1,1
```

This won't work with non ascii characters like `ü` in certain locales (eg `LC_ALL=POSIX`, `LANG=C`). It will split names on those characters.

You can split on delimiter characters instead, like the awk, which is more flexible:

```
grep -Eo '[^[:space:],]+' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn -k1,1
```

Comment: Using `'[[:space:],]+'` as the field separator makes sense, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need awk for this, try simply adding the [-o directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002do) to the grep command in the for loop. That should find each string match and output the matches 1 per line, which wc can easily handle.